# Отправка почты с помощью Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Пыталась настроить отправку, не получилась.
Собрала примерно такой код. Он работает, проблем нет, но мне нужно не автоматическое срабатывание, а требуется непосредственно запускать его вручную, дергая в нужном методе. Как внести изменения не понимаю...

**EmailService**

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMessage(final Mail mail){
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        message.setText(mail.getContent());
        message.setTo(mail.getTo());
        message.setFrom(mail.getFrom());

        emailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

**Mail**

```
public class Mail {

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String content;

    public Mail() {
    }

    public Mail(String from, String to, String subject, String content) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mail{" +
                "from='" + from + '\'' +
                ", to='" + to + '\'' +
                ", subject='" + subject + '\'' +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**MailSenderMainSend**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MailSenderMainSend implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {

        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("*********");
        mail.setTo("********");
        mail.setSubject("Попытка отправить");
        mail.setContent("Ты получил письмо?");

            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail);
    }
}
```

**MailsenderApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MailsenderApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MailsenderApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

Comment: ну так вызывайте метод там, где это нужно.

Comment: Если вызывать mailSenderMainSend.run(); то требуется указать аргументы, но какие?  Если в классе MailSenderMainSend убрать наследование, то при вызове метода будет ошибка вида: Cannot invoke "com.example.mailsender.MailSenderMainSend.run()" because "com.example.mailsender.MailsenderApplication.mailSenderMainSend" is null

Answer (score 1):

ваш класс `MailSenderMainSend` реализует интерфейс для запуска программы в Spring Boot, это нужно для успешной передачи в функцию `SpringApplication.run()`. Также метод `SpringApplication.run()` посредством инкапсуляции переопределяется, чтобы вы могли записать туда ваш код. Считайте, что точка входа в программу находится в

```
@Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {

        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("*********");
        mail.setTo("********");
        mail.setSubject("Попытка отправить");
        mail.setContent("Ты получил письмо?");
        emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail);
    }
```

Поэтому при запуске у вас будет отправляться письмо сразу. Если вы хотите непосредственно взаимодействовать где-то в другом классе, то в методе, где вы хотите отправить ваше письмо, напишите эти строки

```
Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("*********");
        mail.setTo("********");
        mail.setSubject("Попытка отправить");
        mail.setContent("Ты получил письмо?");
        emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail);
```

Вы молодец, что занимаетесь этим, но ваш вопрос больше касается архитектуры, чем вызова метода. Когда вы пишете какую-либо программу, вы должны продумать её архитектуру, то есть какой класс где будет создан, и какой метод будет вызван. Как я понял, вы хотите разработать веб-сайт с функцией отправки эмайла, чтобы это сделать я рекомендую познакомится с шаблоном проектирования MVC (model view controler) и непосредственно уже в контролере принимать с view (то есть вашей веб страницы) данные с `<form>` и задавать их при помощи сеттера в ваш класс `mail`, и при помощи `emailService.sendSimpleMessage()` его отправлять.

Расскажу ещё про `ApplicationArguments`: этот класс представляет собой аргументы, переданные программе; первым аргументом автоматически передаётся путь к вашей программе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я надеюсь я всё понятно объяснил, если что спрашивайте (ещё раз посмотрите шаблон проектирования MVC, понадобится зависимость (SpringMVC). Составьте такую  архитектуру, чтобы `sendMail` вызывался в нужном месте.

Также дам [ссылку на плейлист](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAma_mKffTOR5o0WNHnY0mTjKxnCgSXrZ&si=DHK6rwDMPsIyPjMJ), там автор хорошо очень подробно объясняет, что такое spring, SpringMVC.

Этот плей лист даст вам знания, как непосредственно происходит отправка-приём данных. В ходе данного плейлиста запуск программы осуществляется при помощи уже готового сервера Tomcat, но вы можете вместо него использовать ваш Spring Boot. ознакомьтесь и с видео из  [этого плейлиста](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFUYDRzvocu5EsFGBqPM7CIw&si=t1vIi5U0n20l27E-), не очень хороший автор, но для быстрого старта пойдёт.